# Can't seem to loop trough all the data in the pages on this website - Python, Selenium and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Can not seem to loop trough all the data of all the pages.

```
for i in range(10):
    for media in ul.find_all('div', class_='media-body'):
        cname = media.find('h6').text.strip()
        cdiv = media.find('div').text.strip()
        ctype = media.find('p').text.strip()
        result = [cname, cdiv, ctype]
        print(result)
        print()

    nextPage = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/ul[2]/li[12]/a')
    nextPage.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    time.sleep(5)
```

When I try to scrape data on this website, I get the data from the first page, but not from all the page.

I can see with Selenium that it is looping trough all the pages but when I use Selenium find the "next" button, I only get the list on the first page.

What I want is to get 10 results per page (there are 10 pieces of data) and there are 10 pages so I should get 100 result in the end

What i get is the results of the first page x10.

This is what I actually get, but x10:

```
['GONG APHASIE', 'Santé, Biotech, Chimie - Health Tech', 'L’application qui rétablit la communication grâce aux images']

['SURFY', 'SSII & NTIC - Big Data', 'Solution digitale de centralisation des plans et des données en mode SaaS']

['YRCASH', 'Finance', 'Gestion dématérialisée de votre trésorerie']

['NAHIBU', 'Santé, Biotech, Chimie - Diagnostique, Analyse', "Commercialise un kit d'analyse de votre microbiote intestinal"]

['JERONIMOOOO', 'Emploi, Job', 'Permettre aux indépendants de mettre en place un réseau efficient pour leur activité professionnelle']

['HELLOHOME', 'Immobilier, BTP, Architecture - Immobilier', "Met en relation des personnes cherchant un bien à louer ou acheter, et les professionnels de l'immobilier"]

['MILVUE', 'Santé, Biotech, Chimie - Accessoires médicaux', "L'Intelligence Artificielle Pour La Radiologie d'Urgence"]

['CALA', 'Restauration, Cuisine, Alimentation', "Le premier restaurant de pâtes, où le cuisto c'est le robot"]

['URBASSIST', 'Services aux particuliers', 'Le premier assistant d’urbanisme en ligne']

['BEAUTYCAB', 'Mode, Textile, Beauté - Cosmétique', 'Votre espace beauté où vous voulez, quand vous voulez']

['GONG APHASIE', 'Santé, Biotech, Chimie - Health Tech', 'L’application qui rétablit la communication grâce aux images']

['SURFY', 'SSII & NTIC - Big Data', 'Solution digitale de centralisation des plans et des données en mode SaaS']
```

Comment: This is not a good way to use use xpaths, use especific elements class id or some atribute. post url o html button code for more help

Comment: thats the website but you have to have an account to see the other pages: https://www.myfrenchstartup.com/fr/recherche-avancee
My problem is that it doesnt have any button, the "Next" page is the following code : <a href="javascript:recherche_startup(2)"> → </a> so its loaded with javascript

Comment: Try this xpath="//a[@href='javascript:recherche_startup(2)']" . You can try in devtools manually

Comment: Tried it, same result, but it stops at page 2 now.
I dont know why I cant seem to reach the data of other pages

Comment: Maybe you have to obtaine ul each time after clicked next page. Post errors will help

Comment: I dont get any error, my beautifulsoup script just doesnt reach the other pages, while I can see with selenium that it goes trough all 10 pages